# Is possible to get sound duration without waiting onload?

Tags: actionscript-2

Need to get sounds duration into memory.

```
var sound = new Sound(this);

function getSoundDuration(soundName:String):Number
{
    var dur = 0;
    sound.onLoad = function (success:Boolean) {
        if (success) {
            dur = this.duration;
        }
    };
    sound.loadSound(soundName, false);

    return dur;
}

var DoS1 = getSoundDuration("sound1.mp3");
var DoS2 = getSoundDuration("sound2.mp3");
trace(DoS2);
trace(DoS2);
```

is that possible without wait onLoad to finish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not, the sound needs to be loaded in order to read the metadata. If you are using static sound files, you could hard code those values.